# Euler form - Finding a set amount of vertices around a central point

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations, change-of-basis

When finding a coordinate using Euler form, why do we use:
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
u(x,y) &= x\cos(a) - y\sin(a) \\
v(x,y) &= x\sin(a) + y\cos(a) 
\end{aligned} \right. 
$$
with $a$ being the angle.

I need to know why you switch this $\cos$ and $\sin$ around for $u$ and $v$ as well as why it's subtract for $u$ and add for $v$?

Comment: $(u,v)$ is a rotation of $(x,y)$ by an angle $a$.  The rotation is achieved by pre-multiplying $(x,y)$ by the rotation matrix, which one can show is given by $\\R = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(a) && -\sin(a) \\ \sin(a) && \cos(a) \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about polar coordinates. If
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
x &= r\cos(\theta) \\
y &= r\sin(\theta) 
\end{aligned} \right. 
$$
for some $(r, \theta)$. The crucial observation is that in the new coordinate system rotated through angle $a$, the polar coordinates are $(r, \theta + a)$. In other words, the radial distance remains unchanged, and the angle coordinate *shifts* by $a$.

The new rectangular (cartesian) coordinates $(u, v)$ in terms of these new polar coordinates are
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
u &= r\cos(\theta + a) \\
v &= r\sin(\theta + a) 
\end{aligned} \right. 
$$

Now, we apply the [sum-of-angles identities](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_trigonometric_identities?#/Angle_sum_and_difference_identities) to obtain the result:
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
u &= r \, \bigl( \cos \theta \cos a - \sin \theta \sin a \bigr) 
= (r \cos \theta) \cos a - (r \sin \theta) \sin a 
= x \, \cos a - y \, \sin a\\
v &= r \, \bigl( \cos \theta \sin a + \sin \theta \cos a \bigr) 
= (r \cos \theta) \sin a + (r \sin \theta) \cos a
= x \, \sin a + y \, \cos a
\end{aligned} \right. 
$$